# Change Selected ImageButton Background

Tags: android, xamarin

I have the following implementation in the iOS and it works very well.

```
private void States(UIButton button, UIImage unselectedImage, UIImage selectedImage) 
{
    button.SetImage (unselectedImage, UIControlState.Normal);
    button.SetImage (selectedImage, UIControlState.Selected);
    button.SetImage (selectedImage, UIControlState.Selected | UIControlState.Highlighted);
}
```

I am trying to implement same functionality in the Android.Xamarin, I have implemented `ImageButton` rather than `Button`. I would like to know how to change background of selected or unselected button in `Android.Xamarin`?

```
private void States(ImageButton button, string unselectedImage, string selectedImage) 
{
    // I could not able to change the background of the selected/unselected UmageButton
}
```

I have came across the following site (http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/imageview/display_an_image/), however there are two properties (`button+imageView`) are defined to change button background image. I think that ImageButton should include all of these features in all-in-one.

---

The following xml, it only highlights one, it does not remain highlighted.I want to remain highlighted.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
      android:state_enabled="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_view_off" />
  <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_view_on" />
  <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_view_on" />
  <item
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_view_off" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [selectors](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/form_elements/custom_button/).

The idea is that you define a different `drawable` for each state:

```
  <item
      android:state_enabled="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/disabledbutton" />
  <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/pressedbutton" />
  <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/focusedbutton" />
  <item
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/normalbutton" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Glorfindel, I have a series of buttons, all of them are linked to same action. How could I handle it?

Comment: You can use the same selector for multiple buttons.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for the quick answer. However, each button has different background images. How could I handle it? For example, when user click on delete button, background image should change from `delete_off.png` to `delete_on.png`, similar to following `view_button_on.png`, `measure_button_on.png`, etc. By the way, I have upvoted your answer. I will mark as an answer if you could help me a lot a little bit further.

Comment: Well, then you need to define multiple `.xml`s. That they are linked to the same action doesn't matter. (And thanks for the upvote.)

Comment: if I have 20 buttons with same action, do you believe to create 20 xml is the best way to solve that issue? Is there any better approach?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the best way. Google/Android offers [no real alternatives](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Glorfindel. Could you please check my updated question based on your answer. By the way, I have marked as an answer. I would be glad if you could able to help me out for the updated part of my question.

Comment: That link doesn't help you any further - it's about an ImageView which can be changed by a Button.